# WEB приложение, WEB сервис и проброс NTLM аутентификации

Tags: c#, asp.net, веб-служба, ntlm

Есть ВЭБ сервис и ВЭБ приложение, они крутяться в одном и том же домене под именем пользователя этого домена (например Domain\ASPnet). 
Режим аутентификации у обоих приложений стоит NTLM. В ВЭБ приложении я подключаю ВЭБ сервис:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="PrintSoap"
               closeTimeout="00:10:00"
               openTimeout="00:10:00"
               receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
               sendTimeout="00:10:00"
               allowCookies="false"
               bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
               hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
               maxBufferSize="65536"
               maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
               messageEncoding="Text"
               textEncoding="utf-8"
               transferMode="Buffered"
               useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://comp.domain.ru/WEBService/Service.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PrintSoap"
    contract="PrintServiceReference.PrintSoap" name="PrintSoap" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Теперь я обращаюсь к ВЭБ сервису в коде ВЭБ приложения

```
object result = (new PrintServiceReference.PrintSoapClient()).Something();
```

однако

```
((HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity).User.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount).Value
```

в ВЕБ приложении я получаю `Domain\User`
а в ВЭБ сервисе уже `Domain\ASPnet`

Вопрос: Как мне пробросить NTLM аутентификацию на ВЭБ сервис?

UPD: Сервис Service.asmx.cs

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://comp.domain.ru/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class Service : WebService
{
  [WebMethod]
public object Something()
{
   return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
}
```

в методе идет Exception `Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.`

Comment: Попробуйте использовать на стороне сервиса аутентификацию по токену.

Comment: Кстати, в веб-сервисе надо использовать не `HttpContext`, а `OperationContext`

Comment: OperationContext  выдаёт Exception, может метод надо делать как-то иначе

Comment: Откройте отладчик и посмотрите, на каком из шагов выходит `null`.

Comment: OperationContext.Current

Comment: Стоп, так вы используете Asp.NET WEB Services? А зачем тогда вы в вопросе конфигурацию WCF привели? Это же совершенно разные библиотеки...

Comment: С пустой конфигурацией я вообще достучаться до сервиса не могу, сервис требует NTLM.

Comment: А, то есть у вас сервер - на WebServices, а клиент - на WCF?.. Зачем? Чтобы всех запутать?)

Comment: Клиент это вэб приложение asp.net и сервис это тоже asp.net, я привел пример, что написано у меня в Web.config